# Custom locale settings when launching program from KDE menu

Tags: kde, thunderbird, locale

In KDE, I have noticed that GTK programs don't use the locale settings I specify in the KDE system settings, but rather the system-wide default locale. I want to change this behavior for Thunderbird, in particular.

I can do this in a terminal by running `export LANG=sv_SE.UTF-8; nice thunderbird` but I cannot figure out how to apply these settings when launching Thunderbird from the KDE kicker menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to create this file:

```
$ cat ~/bin/thunderbird
#!/bin/sh
export LANG=sv_SE.UTF-8
exec /usr/bin/thunderbird $@
```

and make it executable: `chmod +x ~/bin/thunderbird`

You may need to log out and log in again, if the `~/bin` folder didn't exist previously.